# Setting state with AJAX requests,using redux-thunk

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm playing around with redux-thunk and trying to fetch data from a random API and I got a question:
As you can see on the screenshot of my console, I get an empty array 2 times when console-logging users' data, which really sucks. Seems like I'm doing something wrong. How do I go about making the request so it doesn't log an empty array? Requesting the data in componentWillMount yields the same result.

Store:

```
  const initialState = {
  users: {
    isFetching: false,
    receivedAt: null,
    error: null,
    userList: []
  }
}

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(
    thunk,
    createLogger()
  )
)
```

Reducers:

```
function users(state = {},action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case 'REQUEST_USERS':
    return {
      ...state,
      isFetching:true
    }

    case 'RECEIVE_USERS':
    return {
      ...state,
      isFetching: false,
      receivedAt: action.receivedAt,
      userList: action.users
    }
    case 'REQUEST_ERROR':
    return {
      ...state,
      error: action.err
    }

    default: return state
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  users
})
```

ActionCreators:

```
export function requestUsers() {
  return {
    type:'REQUEST_USERS'
  }
}

function receiveUsers(users) {
  return {
    type:'RECEIVE_USERS',
    users: users.results,
    receivedAt: Date.now()
  }
}

function requestError(err) {
  return {
    type:'REQUEST_ERROR',
    err
  }
}

export function loadUsers () {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestUsers())
    return fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(users => dispatch(receiveUsers(users)))
    .catch(err => dispatch(requestError(err)))
  }
}
```

container's code:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    users: state.users
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
}

const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main)
```

My component's code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadUsers()
  }

  render() {
    const {userList} = this.props.users
    console.log(userList)
    const users = userList.map((user,i) => <li key={i}>{user.name.first + ' ' + user.name.last}</li>)
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {users}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: it's really hard to say without seeing more of the code (reducers, how you connect to the store, etc.)

and please, indent the code, it's giving me a headache

Comment: Added to the post. I connected to the store, using connect(mapStatetoProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Main)

Comment: Sry, I don't get how to indent code here, it loses all indentation when I paste it.

Comment: since it's such a minimal app, you'd better post the whole thing here - try inserting 4 spaces for each indent level

Comment: I've finally figured out how to indent the code here, hurray! Added the whole thing.

Comment: I guess I figured it out. Render function is just called two times - upon mounting and upon state change, so it's probably normal what i see this in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess I figured it out. Render function is just called two times - upon mounting and upon state change, so it's probably normal what i see this in the console.

Yes you are correct. Only when the AJAX request returns does it actually add the items to the store.

You can in some occasions (e.g. create / update) predict what the server response will be. In that case you could add the predicted result to the payload of the `REQUEST_USERS` action and get a faster-looking UI.